# How to prevent storing duplicate values in local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm not sure how to explain this but basically I want the user to be alerted when they try to save data that is already in the local storage i.e. user clicks on a save button to save the data to favourites (local storage). But it should say this when they try the second time "This has already been saved, you cannot save again unless you remove the data from the storage" I can get it to display what is in the storage after the user clicks a button to save the data. I'm trying to do this in html and using my external json file that has the stored data to then save it to the browser's local storage. The user should only be allowed to save the data of a property html page for example only once. I tried switching my if and else conditions but I couldn't get it to work.

Javascript Code

```
$(".save").on("click", function() {
console.log("Saving property id to local storage");
try {
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);

    var propIdToAdd = $(this).closest("p").attr("id");

    var myFavouriteProp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));

    if (data.Properties.id == myFavouriteProp) {
        alert("Same property is already favourited!");
    } else(myFavouriteProp == null)
    myFavouriteProp = [];
    myFavouriteProp.push(propIdToAdd);

    localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(myFavouriteProp));
} catch (e) {
    if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
        console.log("Error: Local Storage limit Exceeded");
    } else {
        console.log("Error: Saving to Local Storage");
    }
}

});
$("#viewFavourites").on("click", function() {
console.log("Restoring array data from local storage");

myFavouriteProp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
var output = "<ul>";
if (myFavouriteProp != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Properties.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < myFavouriteProp.length; j++) {
            if (data.Properties[i].id == myFavouriteProp[j]) {
                output += "<li>" + data.Properties[i].id + "</li>";
            }
        }
    }
}
output += "</ul>";
document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = output;
});
});
```

I didn't point this out but, how do I allow it to view all of my id's? i.e prop1, prop2. My save function currently overwrites the old values stored in the local storage. But my old save function allowed me to display all the ID's code shown below:

```
    $(".save").on("click", function(){
  try{
      $(this).attr('disabled',true);

      var propIdToAdd = $(this).closest("p").attr("id");

      var myFavouriteProp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
      if (myFavouriteProp == null) {
          myFavouriteProp = [];
      }
      myFavouriteProp.push(propIdToAdd);

      localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(myFavouriteProp));
  }
  catch(e) {
      if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
          console.log("Error: Local Storage limit exceeds. ");
      }
      else {
          console.log("Error: Saving to local storage.");
      }
  }
  });
```

Also, when I try to add `if (data.Properties.id == myFavouriteProp[0])` it stops my buttons from working. After I click the save button and then click the view button, nothing is displayed. Without [0] it displays the alert box and what is contained in the storage. But like I said, my current code (not the old one) overwrites old data and replaces it with new data. It should not do this. It should allow me to display id values of prop1, prop2, etc. Not prop2 by itself after overwriting the value id prop1. They should not overwrite as they are different ids.

Comment: "This has already been saved, you cannot save again unless you remove the data from the storage" - What? Why would a user want to do that?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, basically the user should only be able to save unique values only once ("id" = "prop1"). I have a button to delete the local storage.

Comment: Your `else` clause is a little odd, since you have `else` followed by a parenthesis `(`, rather than the expected curly bracket `{`. The code following the `else`, but not in parentheses, is always run, since it is not contained within brackets.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that when you save, your `myFavouriteProp` variable is an array that will contain one element, the `propId`. Basically in JSON, it will look like this `[2]`.

In `if (data.Properties.id == myFavouriteProp)` you are comparing `data.Properties.id`, which I assume is an integer, to myFavouriteProp, which is an array (You are making the comparison `2 == [2]`). This will never be true.

I would change the comparison to `if (data.Properties.id == myFavouriteProp[0])` and see if that works better for you. This will be comparing integer value to integer value and should work the way you would expect it to.

Comment: Tried adding this. But I'm not sure what I've done wrong. My button for the "save to favourites" is permanently greyed out after I click the button the first time. It stops being greyed only after clearing the local storage.

Comment: At the top of your save function you have `$(this).attr('disabled', true);` This will always disable the save button when the save button is clicked for the first time. I don't see where in the code it gets re-enabled. To re-enabled it use the function `$(this).removeAttr('disabled')`.

Comment: Oops my bad forgot to remove that. Sorry if I'm not clear, if the user clicked on the button beforehand to store the data to the local storage they should get the alert saying that they have already saved it. How do I do this? When I try to click again no alert shows up. Sorry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Changing the comparison `if (data.Properties.id == myFavouriteProp)` to `if (data.Properties.id == myFavouriteProp[0])` as described in my answer should work. If not, above the aforementioned if statement I would try printing the variables to your console using `console.log(data.Properties.id)` and `console.log(myFavouriteProp)` to see what their values are and if they actually match or not.

Comment: I didn't point this out but, how do I allow it to view all of my id's? i.e prop1, prop2. My save function currently overwrites the old values stored in the storage. But my old save function allowed me to display all the ID's. Edited main post to display old save code.

Comment: It looks like there is no place where you have multiple properties or loop over properties.
I would add a for loop which iterates through your properties and will allow you to view and manipulate them. I would explore some more and run some tests to make sure the variables are what you think they are.

Using the debugging available in many browsers is very helpful. Of these I would say the console, storage inspector and JavaScript debugger will be most helpful to you.

Chrome Dev Tools:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Firefox Dev Tools:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools